# Parser-blocking, cross-origin script on Cloudflare script

Tags: parsing, cross-browser, blocking

We are using Cloudflare on one of our sites and last week we have noticed that the site dosen`t load properly. We can see the following error in the console:

> A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script,
>   http://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=f2befc48d1/cloudflare.min.js,
>   is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if
>   the device has poor network connectivity. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
>   details.

This happens in Firefox and Chrome, since last week as new versions of these browsers came out. We have tried to contact Cloudflare, however there is no reply from them. Inspecting their code we can see the document.write and we haven`t got access to this.

Anyone came across with any solution on this?

Comment: This is an interesting question and I found it personally relevant (2G connections are frequent here) but I don't know if you will find an answer here. You might want to ask for the question to be migrated to a site more oriented to web administration. Make sure you use appropriate tags (http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cloudflare for example).

Comment: To get a question migrated, use the `flag` button under the question, select "in need of moderator attention", and add the site you want the question moved to. (Yes, there should be a simpler way. But there isn't, other than deleting here and then posting there.) There is a rule against double posting, so you have to choose just one site. SO is a programming site, so it's probably not the best.